# Storyboard orientation Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, storyboard, orientation

I need to design an app in landscape mode. I selected the ViewController and went to the attribute inspector and selected the orientation to Landscape but the controller view in storyboard doesn't become in the landscape mode. Please suggest what I am doing wrong. I am using Xcode 6.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the size of view controller is freeform it doesn't rotate. If you can change the size of view controller, you can see it rotating.

[Check this screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79649352/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-14%20at%201.36.23%20pm.png)

Comment: If this helps answer your questions, can you please accept my answer and award me the points. :)

Comment: I am unable to award you point because I do not have enough points. Sorry. But thanks a lot for your help.